# UIActivityViewController doesn't work in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was using UIActivityViewController to share something for my application. It works well in any device prior to iOS8. The problem is the text,images are not be shown in email, twitter, Facebook in iOS 8 device or simulator.

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *textObject = @"Test";
    NSString *urlString = @"http://test.com";
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textObject, url, image, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                     initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                     applicationActivities:nil];

    avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard ];

    [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Did I do anything wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The new Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1 doesn't solve the problem. And it causes crash in email. Here are some screenshots (take email sharing as an example):

1. In iOS 7 (You can see the image)

[image]

2. In iOS 8 (Blank screen)

[image]

> And the app crashes with a "MailCompositionService" exception. The
>   part of the error message is:
>
> Process:               MailCompositionService [3775] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/MailCompositionService.app/MailCompositionService
>   Identifier:            MailCompositionService Version:
>   1.0 (1.0) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        launchd_sim [3725] Responsible:           launchd_sim [3725] User ID: 
>   501
>
> Date/Time:             2014-10-22 10:31:19.064 +0800 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   B1EC6B56-DD7F-36A3-1506-B8CE84AB3FEB
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 9800 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression
>   enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException abort() called
>   CoreSimulator 110.4 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 8.1 (12B411) -
>   DeviceType: iPhone 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be correct in real device but not in simulator.

Comment: I encountered a similar crash simply sending an email (in iOS8 Simulator), with code that worked in iOS7.  MFMailComposeViewController presents, but some fields are missing (e.g., Recipients).  Then after about 3 seconds it crashes as above.  This seems to be a simulator bug, probably related to mail.

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue. however mine is slightly different. I can present the the controller without any actions available. :/ I have remove all of the excludedtypes hoping that I can see any but fails. I guess this is another bug with the latest release of xcode 6.1 and iOS8.